# Erro ao acessar rota liberada com Spring boot

Tags: api, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Boa tarde estou com um problema na liberação de rotas para minha aplicação feita com Spring boot. O problema é que a rota principal "/home" pede o token JWT para acessa-la, porem ela está configurada para permitir qualquer tipo de request de qualquer usuário, com ou sem token. Alguém já teve esse tipo de problema ?

Estava seguindo este tutorial: http://andreybleme.com/2017-04-01/autenticacao-com-jwt-no-spring-boot/

**Arquivo de boot:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Boot
{    
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
   }

   @GetMapping("/home")
   public String home()
   {
      return "home";
   }
}
```

**Arquivo de configuração:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // filtra requisições de login
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                // filtra outras requisições para verificar a presença do JWT no header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // cria uma conta default
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

**Arquivo TokenAuthenticationService:**

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    // EXPIRATION_TIME = 10 dias
    static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 860_000_000;
    static final String SECRET = "9FFE05B4553F32356D4D70F128FF0BB8C19F64275C45153EF26ED127E264A2AA";
    static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, String username) {
        String JWT = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET).compact();

        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    }

    static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (token != null) {
            // faz parse do token
            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Arquivo JWTLoginFilter:**

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    protected JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException {

        AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(request.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        credentials.getUsername(),
                        credentials.getPassword(),
                        Collections.emptyList()
                )
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain,
            Authentication auth) {

        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, auth.getName());
    }    
}
```

**Arquivo JWTAuthenticationFilter:**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService
                .getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remova `.antMatchers("/home").permitAll()` e adicione.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/home");
    }
```

Assim não precisa de autenticação para acessar a rota `"/home"`.